# FaceBook App Invite with custome URL scheme iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, url, applinks

I am trying to realize App Invite feature for iOS app. All works good except custome URL Scheme with parameter (like referral). 
iOS app has two URL Schemas:

```
fb123456789712345:// 
myappurlscheme://
```

Meta tags in web server:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myappurlscheme://fb_app_invite?referral=referralname" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="123456789" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="MyApp" />
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789712345"/>
```

When FB user clicks on the App Invite from their profile i'am expecting than iOS app will be open with URL`(myappurlscheme://fb_app_invite?referral=referralname),` 
but in practice i get URL`(fb123456789712345://authorize#access_token=ZXZXZXZXZXZXZXZXZXZXZX&expires_in=86400&target_url=%2Fappcenter%2$454545454545454%3Frequest_ids%3D3333333333333%26ref%3Dapp_invite_inbox%26content%3Dinvite%222222222222222222)`

I dont know how to figure out to use custome URL Schema for parse referralname. Please, help me. Where i had mistaken?

Comment: Have you tried to create App Link hosted on FB? I checked my implementation and the iOS app is opened with `myappurlscheme://` URL scheme. Go to this FB App Link host for your app: `https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/<YOUR_APP_ID>/?platform=app-links-host` to create the App Link.

Comment: Yep, i created link with FB App Link Tool. Nothing changed, exactly the same url with access_token.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know what causes your issue, thus I don't see any way to figure it out unless comparing things between my and yours implementation. What do you think?